# Stack Overflow redirect exploit used for phishing

Tags: support, phishing

I am just reporting a redirect exploit being used on the Stack Overflow Website. I received the following phishing email that appeared to be from Netflix:

[image]

All hyperlinks use the Stack Overflow domain name, and appear to take advantage of their external link redirect on the company page.

Actual Phishing URL (EDITED TO AVOID READERS FROM FOLLOWING): [https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/a/ext-link?redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2F[PHISING](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/a/ext-link?redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2F%5BPHISING) DOMAIN REMOVED]%2Fimages%2Fredirected.php&companyPageId=15983&externalLink=Website

The removed portion is: doceo.com.mx if you are wondering.

I tested it with my own link and it redirected me. I did not go to doceo.com.mx to see if the site was legit or not as it is most likely compromised. I don't know what that website is but if they see this they should check their site for possible issues. Hopefully staff will have already had this reported and fixed by the time you read this, however is there a place to report stuff like this to Stack Overflow or a better place to address this kind of thing? I realize it happens all the time, but finding and fixing these things is important.

Comment: I received the same email as well. I was searching stackoverflow for ways to report this. Shady exploit though.

Comment: Related - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400811/phishing-email-using-stack-overflow-jobs-redirects-to-a-netflix-phishing-site